# Confusion in definition of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I use the following definition of vector space:

**Definition**: Let $\displaystyle ( V,+)$ be an abelian group and $\displaystyle ( F,\oplus ,\ \otimes )$ be a field. I define a mapping $\displaystyle \  .:F\times V\rightarrow V$ and call it an external composition.

Now $\displaystyle V$ is called a vector space if $\displaystyle \forall a,b\ \in F\ \land \ \forall x,y\in V$, we have:

$\displaystyle  1. \  (a+b) .x=a.x+b.x\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

$\displaystyle  2. \   a.( x+y) =a.x+b.y$

$\displaystyle 3. \ ( a\otimes b) .x=a.( b.x)$

$\displaystyle 4.\ 1.x=x$

My confusion is: is property number $3$ above necessary?

**Restatement:** If I restate the above definition as follows: A vector space $V$ over field $F$ is a set along with an addition on $V$ and scaler multiplication on $V$ (this is defined as external composition defined in the above definition)  such that for all $u,v,w \in V$ and $\forall a,b\in F$, the following holds:

**Commutativity**

$u+v=v+u$

**Associativity**

$(u+v)+w=u+(v+w)$

**Existence of Additive identity**

there exists an element $0\in V$ such that $v+0=v$ for all $v\in V$

**Existence of Additive inverse**

For every $v\in V$ there exists an element in $V$ (which we denote by $(-v)$) such that $v+(-v)=0$

**Multiplicative identity**

$1v=v$ for all $v\in V$

**Distributive property**

$a(u+v)=(u+v)a$ and $(a+b)u=au+bu$

What I think is that if property no. $(3)$ stated in the "definition" is not necessary then "restatement" and "definition" are the same and if they are not same then I can't find an example of an abelian group $V$ and field $F$ such that all conditions in "restatement" are satisfied but $(3)$ in "definition" is not satisfied.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple example is $V=\mathbb{R}$, $F=\mathbb{C}$, where we define $(a+bi).x := ax$.

Then for example $i.x = 0$ for all $x$, but this is impossible in the presence of Axiom 3 as we could multiply by $-i$ on both sides to get $x=0$.

In general, we can construct similar examples whenever $F'\subset F$ is a field extension.  By choosing a basis for the extension we can make any vector space over $F'$ into an "unnatural" vector space over $F$.

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The "restatement" is my post above is similar to definition 1.19 in the text Linear Algebra Done Right (LADR). I think that axiom 3 in "definition" in the post was skipped in LADR. Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: It seems you're right, this should be in the definition of what Axler calls a "scalar multiplication".  It seems like multiplicative associativity wasn't on his mind at all, as it's also omitted from the list of "Properties of complex arithmetic".

Comment: Professor Axler is available on this site, I think we should point this out to him.

Comment: @Koro We're wrong, it's there but it's tucked away: in 1.19 he includes both additive and multiplicative associativity under "associativity".  I do think it should be part of "scalar multiplication" though.

Comment: Ahh, you are absolutely right. I overlooked multiplicative associativity in 1.19 as can be seen from my post also. I understood now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Part of scaler multiplication? Why? I mean when we define "external composition", we don't say that it has to comply with associativity.

Comment: If you're using the definition that an external composition is a set map $A\times B \to B$, or equivalently $A\to \operatorname{End}(B)$, this is relevant when $A$ is just a set (or abelian group I suppose).  But we are interested in $\operatorname{End}(B)$ as a monoid under composition, so ultimately we want $A$ to have a monoid structure and for the composition to respect it.